# How to append the preceding rows for the same key for different dates in sql/hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have the below table. i tried doing this using join with lag and lead function but its not giving the expected result. I'm just not getting any clue how to implement the solution for this.

```
name    date       amount
abc     04/06/2018 100
abc     04/06/2018 200
abc     04/13/2018 300
```

now the output i needed is below.

```
name    date             amount
abc     04/06/2018       100
abc     04/06/2018       200
abc     04/13/2018       100
abc     04/13/2018       200
abc     04/13/2018       300
```

so here 300 is the new value and 100,200 from 04/06/2018 will also shown for 04/13/2018 as one row per amount. Do we have any way to do this in hive/sql/sparksql. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a column to specify the ordering, other than the `day` column shown here?

Comment: Its actually a date col with 7 days difference in  different dates values for the same name. I have used day just for example.

Comment: it would be better to show it as dates. also explain if you have to copy over rows from *all previous days or just 1 , 2 .. days*.

Comment: Yes that is the requirement all amount values from previous dates is required.So for Tue all mon amount values should be there. similarly if we have sat so all previous days amount values should be present under sat amount values. updated my question with date cols

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala
 Do you have any approach for this scenario. One thing which is striking me is to implement a UDF.